# ANTLR expression with optional operator + custom AST nodes

Tags: tree, antlr, option-type

recently I had to make a grammar for expressions like:

```
rule1 & rule2 & rule3 => produces binary tree 
  (AndNode (AndNode RuleNode(rule1) RuleNode(rule2)) RuleNode(rule3))
rule1 | (rule2 & rule3) => produces binary tree
  (OrNode RuleNode(rule1) (AndNode RuleNode(rule2) RuleNode(rule3)))
```

RuleNode, AndNode and OrNode are my classes which are going to be used later on when whole expression is being evaluated.
rule1, rule2 etc are simply concepts from my domain and have nothing to do with parser or lexer rules.

Here is the grammar:

```
RULE      : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z')('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9')*;
QUOTE     : '\'';
PARAM     : QUOTE ( ~('\'') )* QUOTE;
LPAREN    : '(';
RPAREN    : ')';
DELIMITER : ',';
AND       : '&';
OR        : '|';
WS        : (' ' | '\t')+ {$channel = HIDDEN;};

params    : LPAREN! PARAM (DELIMITER! PARAM)* RPAREN!;
rule      : RULE<RuleNode>^ params?;

expr      : andexpr;
andexpr   : orexpr (AND<AndNode>^ orexpr)*;
orexpr    : atom (OR<OrNode>^ atom)*;
atom      : rule | LPAREN! expr RPAREN!;

parse     : expr;
```

Everything worked perfectly fine until I get requirement to make AND operator a default one, so I could write my examples like:

```
rule1 rule2 rule3
rule1 | (rule2 rule3)
```

I tried to specify anexpr rule in a different ways:

1)

```
andexpr   : orexpr+ -> (^(AND<AndNode> orexpr))+;
```

Result - produces tree which is not a binary tree and does not even have AndNode as root:

```
(nil RuleNode(rule1) RuleNode(rule2) RuleNode(rule3))
```

2)

Based on the very first example from [ANTLR Tree Construction](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Tree+construction) (Operators section) I tried also:

```
andexpr   : (a=orexpr->$a) (b=orexpr -> ^(AND<AndNode> $andexpr $b))*;
```

Result - same flat tree as in 1)

If I remove custom node  from 2):

```
andexpr   : (a=orexpr->$a) (b=orexpr -> ^(AND $andexpr $b))*;
```

then parser produces binary tree:

```
(AND (AND RuleNode(rule1) RuleNode(rule2)) RuleNode(rule3))
```

but unfortunately AND is not my custom AndNode. I suspect it has something to do with AndNode construction - in original example with '&' required the consructor is

```
AndNode(Token token) { this.token = token; }
```

but for grammar with optional '&' I had to implement a new one

```
AndNode(int type) { }
```

which no longer accepts Token as a param.

Please help me write rule for this case so I would have both binary tree and custom node! I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `^({new AndNode(AND)} ...` instead of `^(AND<AndNode> ...`.

Comment: Yes 280Z28 I could use {new AndNode(AND)} but it does not help. The thing is that AND which is passed to AndNode constructor is only a node type constant (integer) not a Token object. I think that Token object is required for tree to be correctly constructed. If I have expression like "rule1 rule2" then there's no Token corresponding to optional '&' operator. And my question was - what I can do to make whitespace between rules behaving like operator (a real Token)?:)